# selecting a date range is not functioning as desired in mongo

Tags: mongodb, date, pymongo

I wish to select a range of dates using query, but it looks like I have the timezone formatted dates, however I thought these were wrapped as the date object so that I can use the date object in python/pymongo. However when I use the query, I do not get what I expect. I tried also converting date to ISODate. So my question is, should I:

a) Reload all the date data in a different format. 
b) Work with the dates in mongo as they are.

Below I'm stringing together multiple options, hence the or, but for the case I have for example:

```
query = {}
query["$or"] = []
query["$or"].append({"date_object": {"$lte": time_to.isoformat(), "$gte": time_from.isoformat() } })
```

giving:

```
query = {'platform': {'$in': [re.compile('windows', re.IGNORECASE)]}, '$or': [{'date_object': {'$gte': '2016-04-14T18:02:02.862030', '$lte': '2016-04-28T18:02:02.862030'}}]}
```

Also if I try the following (using the datetime object), I get the same issue.

```
query = {}
query["$or"] = []
query["$or"].append({"date_object": {"$lte": time_to, "$gte": time_from } })

query = {'platform': {'$in': [re.compile('windows', re.IGNORECASE)]}, '$or': [{'date_object': {'$gte': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 15, 7, 14, 7, 269376), '$lte': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 29, 7, 14, 7, 269376)}}]}
```

The documents are like this for example.

```
{
        "_id": 889,
        "date_object": [
            {
                "$date": "2014-01-27T00:00:00.000Z"
            },
            {
                "$date": "2015-04-20T00:00:00.000Z"
            },
            {
                "$date": "2016-05-09T00:00:00.000Z"
            }
        ]
    }
```

So `_id==889` is returned even though the dates are not in the range specified in the original query.

Comment: [isoformat()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat) returns a "string", but the data is a BSON `Date`, so the you just want to pass through a regular [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) instead. It's not a string, but just a serialized representation of a string in your output.

Comment: @NeilLunn I did try this initially before isoformat() but found I got the same behaviour. Any other suggestions?